# Reporte FPDF con Php y MySQL

Tags: mysqli, php5, fpdf

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Necesito hacer una reporte de estudiantes por asignaturas. en otras palabras que el mismo reporte me muestre solo una vez el nombre del estudiante con el grado y las asignaturas asociadas con este estudiante y grado.

**Datos Del Estudiante**
**nombre  apellido    grado** juan     perez       1

**Datos de Asignaturas y Área**
**asignatura         área**  Matemáticas        Matemáticas Álgebra            Matemáticas Ciencias Nat.      Ciencias Química            Ciencias Física             Ciencia Sociales           Sociales Lenguaje        Lenguaje

pero cuando intento hacer la consulta dentro del reporte me los muestra pero por separado y el estudiante que tenga mas de una asignatura me lo muestra una sola vez.

este es el código que tengo y no se como mejorarlo para que hago lo que necesito

```
<?php
 //  require 'fpdf/fpdf.php';
    require 'plantilla.php';
    require 'conexion.php';

    $pdf = new PDF('P','mm','A4'); 

    $pdf->AliasNbPages();

    //$cedula=$_POST["cedula"]; 

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,25);  //ESTABLE LA DISTANCIA DEL MARGEN INFERIOR EN MILIMETROS

 $query="SELECT estudiantes.nombres,estudiantes.apellidos,asig.asig,area.area,grado.grado
 From estudiantes 
  inner join asig on estudiantes.id_asig=asig.id_asig
  inner join area on asig.id_area=area.id_area
   inner join grado on estudiantes.id_grado=grado.id_grado
  GROUP BY estudiantes.nombres ";

//INNER JOIN asignatura a ON n.Id_Asig1=a.Id_Asig";




 $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);      
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
    for($i=0;$i<1;$i++){
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetY(33); //distancia de la brra que dice datos estuiante con el borde superior
    $pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255); //color texto de la barra NEGRO
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12); //si colocara antes de B que es para negrita colocara U saliera subrayado
    $pdf->Cell(190,4,'Datos de Estudiante',1,0,'C',1);

    $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0); //color texto de la barra NEGRO
    $pdf->SetXY(10,38);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',11);
    $pdf->Cell(70,5,"Nombres y Apellido       Grado",1,0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(10,44);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
    $pdf->Cell(70,5,"  ".utf8_decode($row['nombres']).'   '.utf8_decode($row['apellidos']) .'     '.'    '.utf8_decode($row['grado']),0,0,'C');

    $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0); //color texto de la barra NEGRO
    $pdf->SetXY(10,68);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',11);
    $pdf->Cell(70,5,"Asignatura",1,0,'C',0);
    $pdf->SetXY(10,74);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
    $pdf->Cell(70,5,"  ".utf8_decode($row['asig']).'   '.utf8_decode($row['area']),0,0,'C');



    }
    }
    $pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: antes del GROUP BY..deberias poner un where estudiantes.id = id para que consulte un estudiante en especifico..

Comment: hola de antemano gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: hola de antemano gracias por tu respuesta  ya lo hice pero aún asi me sigue mostrando solo una asignatura por estudiante sera que es porque el id_est es auto_increment   entonces lo hago con la cédula y nada me sigue saliendo igual

Comment: ¿podrías poner el esquema de tu base de datos?

Comment: es una bd de prueba  con campos muy sencillos solo para hacer lo que corresponde en la bd real     TABLA ESTUDIANTE (id_est, cedula,nombres,apellidos, id_asig,id_grado)    TABLE ASIG (id_asig, asig, id_area) TABLA AREA (id_area, area) TABLA GRADO (id_grado, grado)

Comment: Ya agregue la clausula WHERE antes del GROUP BY y cree un formulario para buscar un estudiante en especifico pero aun asi me sigue mostrando solo el estudiante con una sola asignatura y en la base de datos ese mismo estudiante tiene registradas 3 asignaturas

Answer (score 1):

Saludos supongamos tengo la siguiente tabla donde muestro todos los estudiantes:

```
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>Estudiante</td>
    <td>curso</td>
    <td>paralelo</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fernanda</td>
    <td>Noveno</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td><a href="archivo.php?estudiante_id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> Consultar</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Isabel</td>
    <td>Noveno</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td><a href="archivo.php?estudiante_id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> Consultar</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Santiago</td>
    <td>Noveno</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td><a href="archivo.php?estudiante_id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> Consultar</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

si te fijas he agregado un hipervinculo donde agrego el id de cada uno de los registros(estudiantes) esto asumiendo que armo mi tabla con un for o foreach en php.

Ahora al dar click en Consultar me redirigue a una pagina archivo.php que sera donde haga el reporte de c/u de los estudiantes y recibo el parametro algo asi:

**archivo.php:**

```
<?php

    require 'plantilla.php';
    require 'conexion.php';
    //RECIBO EL ID DEL ESTUDIANTE
    $id_Estudiante = $_GET['estudiante_id'];

    $pdf = new PDF('P','mm','A4'); 

    $pdf->AliasNbPages();

    //$cedula=$_POST["cedula"]; 

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,25);  //ESTABLE LA DISTANCIA DEL MARGEN INFERIOR EN MILIMETROS

 $query="SELECT estudiantes.nombres,estudiantes.apellidos,asig.asig,area.area,grado.grado
 From estudiantes 
  inner join asig on estudiantes.id_asig=asig.id_asig
  inner join area on asig.id_area=area.id_area
   inner join grado on estudiantes.id_grado=grado.id_grado WHERE estudiantes.id= ".$id_Estudiante."
  GROUP BY estudiantes.nombres ";



 $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);      
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
    for($i=0;$i<1;$i++){
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetY(33); //distancia de la brra que dice datos estuiante con el borde superior
    $pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255); //color texto de la barra NEGRO
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12); //si colocara antes de B que es para negrita colocara U saliera subrayado
    $pdf->Cell(190,4,'Datos de Estudiante',1,0,'C',1);

    $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0); //color texto de la barra NEGRO
    $pdf->SetXY(10,38);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',11);
    $pdf->Cell(70,5,"Nombres y Apellido       Grado",1,0,'C',0);
$pdf->SetXY(10,44);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
    $pdf->Cell(70,5,"  ".utf8_decode($row['nombres']).'   '.utf8_decode($row['apellidos']) .'     '.'    '.utf8_decode($row['grado']),0,0,'C');

    $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0); //color texto de la barra NEGRO
    $pdf->SetXY(10,68);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',11);
    $pdf->Cell(70,5,"Asignatura",1,0,'C',0);
    $pdf->SetXY(10,74);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
    $pdf->Cell(70,5,"  ".utf8_decode($row['asig']).'   '.utf8_decode($row['area']),0,0,'C');



    }
    }
    $pdf->Output()
?>
```

ya con esto tan solo resta probar en ir adaptando el codigo a tus necesidades..!!

Comment: ok déjame probar y te comento muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: amigo  la verdad por ser nuevo quizás es que este varado en esto que debe ser tan sencillo. Ya busque algunas formas de tratar de hacer lo que me dices y nada no logro resultados

Comment: deberias mostrar la parte en donde cargas todos los registros de los estudiantes... porque desde alli asumo que es donde vas a consultar cada uno de ellos

Comment: mira esta es la tabla ESTUDIANTES (id_est,cedula,nombres,apellidos,id_asig,id_grado)

Comment: me referia a tu html donde los muestras edita tu pregunta y agrega esa parte

Comment: editala aca: https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/241142/edit

Comment: mira esta es bd de prueba para hacer lo que me toca la tabla ESTUDIANTES (id_est,cedula,nombres,apellidos,id_asig,id_grado)  en la bd ya existen 2 registros de un estudiante llamado juan perez y 3 de un estudiante llamado pablo ortiz.    porque existen tres registros porque cada uno de ellos ocupa una asignatura diferente.    entonces yo lo que busco es que cuando yo muestre el reporte me lo presente en dos hojas una para juan con todas la asignaturas de el  y uno para pablo con todas las asignaturas de él.    y me sale cada uno en una hoja por separado con las asignaturas en cada hoja ...

Comment: ya coloque una imagen de lo que quiere mostrar en el reporte pdf

Comment: ya lo hice como me dijo diego avila creando  las siguientes paginas  un formulario de busqueda del id que se digita y en otra me  muestra el resultado de la consulta pero al hacer clic para el hipervinculo que crea el reporte me lo manda en blanco